# What is DEX Compilation?

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie with android studio and want to know the difference between `DEX compilation` and `DX compilation`.Recently I read about DX compiler in Android studio 3.1. So, can anyone here explain me what is difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

**DEX** compilation is the process of transforming .class bytecode into .dex bytecode for the Android Runtime (or Dalvik, for older versions of Android).

**DX** is DEX compiler.

What you read about is probably the new D8 compiler that Google introduced with Android Studio 3.0. In Android Studio 3.1 it will replace DX as default.